# Is there a way to check how many times a string has been returned?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently fiddling around with a basic rock, paper, scissors game over on [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/macnor44/9t5m47ob/2/), and my current objective is to make the app generally more user-friendly. Is there a way to track the number of times that a string has been returned and display that number?

I adapted this from a fellow JSFiddle member and the exercise on Codecademy, so some of the code may look familiar.

```
$('#begin').click(function() {
  playRPS();
  return false;
});

var playRPS = function() {
  var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
  var compChoice = computerChoice();
  var result = compare(userChoice, compChoice);
  $('body').append('<p>You chose ' + userChoice + '</p>')
    .append('<p>The computer chose ' + compChoice + '</p>')
    .append('<p>' + result + '</p>');
};

var computerChoice = function() {
  var randomNum = Math.random();
  if (randomNum < 0.34) {
    randomNum = "rock";
  } else if (randomNum <= 0.67) {
    randomNum = "paper";
  } else {
    randomNum = "scissors";
  }
  return randomNum;
}

var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
  if (choice1 === choice2)
    return "The result is a tie!";
  if (choice1 === "rock") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors")
      return "You win";
    else
      return "The Computer wins";
  }
  if (choice1 === "paper") {
    if (choice2 === "rock")
      return "You win";
    else
      return "The Computer wins";
  }
  if (choice1 === "scissors") {
    if (choice2 === "rock")
      return "You win";
    else
      return "The Computer wins";
  }
  if (choice1 === "bomb") {
    return "Well Played, You win";
  }
};
```

Comment: Just a heads up, you need to swap scissors for the comparison at the bottom of your code - it currently states scissors beats rock :)

Comment: Could you please mark the line, where that string is returned?

Comment: @DKyleo Thanks for the heads up, the issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a counter to accomplish that. It's not something I find myself doing very often these days, but people do use them occasionally.

```
let counter = 0;

if (true) {
  counter += 1;
}

console.log(counter); // Would log 1 to the console.
```

You could loop over this and every time you passed the conditional, it would add 1 to the value in the variable called counter.

In your case, you could just add a counter for each result on the line above your returns.

Comment: The simplest and most effective answer :)

Comment: This is probably a simple question, but how do I set it to loop?

Comment: As in, which loop would you recommend I use?

Comment: I think in your case you don't even need a loop, you can declare the variable outside of your function and just increment it right before you return.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes. There are multiple ways. If you have a function that returns multiple strings you can, for example, use an object to keep track of the number:

```
var counter = {}

var str = functionCall();

if (counter.hasOwnProperty(str))
 {
    counter[str] ++;
 }
else
{
   // Initialize the property before you can increment
   counter[str] = 1;
}

console.log(counter[str]);
```

That gives you an object that has as many counters as you like. It's a bit more advantageous than a counter variable for each string

Answer (score 0):

Just keep count of it in a global variable:

```js
$('#begin').click(function() {
  playRPS();
  return false;
});
// we will keep count of what each player played in this object
var counts = {
  computer: { rock: 0, paper: 0, scissors: 0, bomb: 0 },
  player: { rock: 0, paper: 0, scissors: 0, bomb: 0 }
};

var playRPS = function() {
  var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
  // if the user choice is known, then it should have a number type entry in counts
  if (typeof counts.player[userChoice] !== 'number') {
    // user error handling
    $('body').append('<p>Unknown choice: ' + userChoice + '</p>');
    return;
  }
  // increment count for current player choice
  counts.player[userChoice] += 1;
  var compChoice = computerChoice();
  var result = compare(userChoice, compChoice);
  var pCount = counts.player[userChoice];
  var cCount = counts.computer[compChoice];
  $('body').append(
    '<p>You chose ' +
    userChoice +
    ' (' + pCount + ' time' + (pCount > 1 ? 's' : '')  + ')' +
    '</p>')
    .append(
    '<p>The computer chose ' +
    compChoice +
    ' (' + cCount + ' time' + (cCount > 1 ? 's' : '')  + ')' +
    '</p>')
    .append('<p>' + result + '</p>');
};

var computerChoice = function() {
  var randomNum = Math.random();
  let choice = null;
  // gives a very little chance to computer of bombing you
  if (randomNum < 0.0001) {
    choice = "bomb";
  } else if (randomNum < 0.34) {
    choice = "rock";
  } else if (randomNum <= 0.67) {
    choice = "paper";
  } else {
    choice = "scissors";
  }
  // increment count for current computer choice
  counts.computer[choice] += 1;
  return choice;
}

var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
  if (choice1 === choice2)
    return "The result is a tie!";
  if (choice1 === "rock") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors")
      return "You win";
    else
      return "The Computer wins";
  }
  if (choice1 === "paper") {
    if (choice2 === "rock")
      return "You win";
    else
      return "The Computer wins";
  }
  if (choice1 === "scissors") {
    if (choice2 === "paper")
      return "You win";
    else
      return "The Computer wins";
  }
  if (choice2 === "bomb") {
    return "Computer bombed you, You lose";
  }
  if (choice1 === "bomb") {
    return "Well Played, You win";
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="begin" value="Begin"/>
```